# Is the output of this DC-DC converter considered a differential pair?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, differential

Very new to electronics.

I am using [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/traco-power/TRN-1-1223/9345702) DC-DC converter in one of my designs. It is a dual output (+/- 15V) DC-DC converter. I have read a few articles about how important it is to keep differential pairs (that is, as I understand, traces carrying signals of equal amplitude and opposite polarity) at equal length and close together.

Are the two outputs of such DC-DC converters considered a differential pair? Given that they are DC... Does that play a role? Should I keep them close together in my PCB and length match them or not?

Comment: The advice you cite about differential pairs is almost exclusively regarding wires/traces that carry AC signals rather than DC voltage/current like your converter output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, an output of a power supply is not a differential output pair in the sense like e.g RS-485, CAN, LVDS, USB or other differential data outputs are.

You don't need to length match power supply rail wiring, as you must always provide power where you need it.

Keeping them close together may be a good idea nevertheless, as it is a good idea to minimize the loop area of the wiring to prevent the wiring to be a coil that emits interference. But in only applies to current source and return paths. If the currents on +15V wire get returned on 0V ground wire then minimize that loop as the -15V wire then does not relate to those. If currents on +15V wire get returned on the -15V wire, then 0V ground wire is irrelevant.